# How to refer a file system in Cloudbess?

Tags: java, executable-jar, cloudbees

I'm new to Cloudbees. I just opened an account and trying to upload a .JAR file which basically downloads a file to the location mentioned by user (through java command line arguments). So far I have run the .JAR in my local. So far, I was referring to my local file system to save the file. If I deploy my .JAR file to Cloudbees SDK, where can I save the downloaded file (and then process it).

NOTE: I know this is not a new requirement in java if we deploy the jar in UNIX/WINDOWS OS where we can refer the file system w.r.t to home directory.

Edit#1:
I've seen couple of discussions about the same topic. 
[link#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21590659/uploading-a-file-spring-mvc-cloudbees)
 [link#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384103/store-files-in-cloud-using-java-ee?rq=1)

Everywhere they are talking about the ephemeral (temporary) file system which we can access through `System.getProperty("java.io.tempDir")`. But I'm getting `null` when I access `java.io.tempDir`. Did anyone manage to save files temporarily using this tempDir?

Comment: I could access /tmp/ directory to save my files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload a jar with the java stack specifying the class and classpath (http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Java+Container)

Our filesystem however is not persistent, so if you are talking about saving a file from within your application, you could save it in this path

System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")

but it will be gone when your application hibernates, scales-up/down or is redeployed.

If you want a persistent way to store file/images, you can use AmazonS3 from your cloudbees application: uploading your files there will ensure their persistence.
You can find an example of how to do that in this clickstart:
http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/search?q=amazon+s3

More information here: https://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/File+system+access

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

By "Upload jar I meant deploy the jar file in Cloubbees". Anyways now I could deploy my jar in Cloudbees. 

When I tested, `System.getProperty("java.io.tempDir")` is returning `null` when I run the jar file in cloudbees. So, do we have to set this path to any cloudbees specific file system?

Comment: I have updated my answer, the right variable name is java.io.tmpdir